# Accessing kubernetes pods dynamically via ingress based on their POD ID

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, nginx-ingress

lets say I have 1 deployment running 3 PODs

```
$ kubectl get pods                                                                         
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
app-8f7f4678b-7fd4q           2/2     Running   0             7d16h
app-8f7f4678b-pgs86           2/2     Running   0             7d16h
app-8f7f4678b-wqgx4           2/2     Running   0             7d16h
```

App is accessible on `app.example.com` via nginx-ingress. This app shows POD id, for example `7fd4q` on frontend and whenever app is accessed, it shows at the bottom which POD is being accessed. As ingress is set to be sticky, once the user accesses app, he stays on it. For debugging purposes and also for app specific functions, like cleaning out the cache, I would like that specific POD could be accessed from the web, for example `app-8f7f4678b-7fd4q` could be accessed on `app-7fd4q.example.com`. Is this type of dynamic proxying possible? I know I can access PODs with `kubectl port-forward` but its not feasible by other users/admins.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a wildcard DNS entry for your domain example.com to point to the IP address of your nginx-ingress controller. Update your existing Ingress configuration to handle the wildcard subdomain routing. Expose each Pod individually by creating a corresponding Service for each Pod. Add additional rules to your Ingress configuration to route the subdomains to the specific app Pods.
Remember to adjust the host values and add rules for each individual Pod you want to access via a subdomain. Update DNS records: Update your DNS records to include the necessary subdomains